# Are the renewable stumps in the new forest farm hardwood?

Tags: stardew-valley

In the new update, there are 4 new farm layouts to choose from at game start. One of these is the forest farm, one perk of which is renewable stumps that you can use for more wood. Do any of these stumps provide hardwood like the stumps in the Secret Woods do? Also, what tier axe is required to chop them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The respawning stumps found in the Forest Farm layout are exactly the same as the stumps found on the standard farm and in the secret woods. They drop two Hardwood each and require a Copper Axe or better.